# How to get "last year from [spec year] that has posts"?

Tags: pagination, archives

I have a year archive like this:

◀ **2010** - - - - - - - - - - - **2011** - - - - - - - - - - - **2012** ►

And first I had the idea that a year with no posts would be just the same page with the text "No posts found". But I got trouble with that since pages with no content redirects to 404. And that made me realise that that actually is the best. It's more SEO friendly.

So I started to thinking how I will solve the pagination situation. And got this idea, if 2010 doesn't have any posts. That year number will be just grey text and not a link. And the last year with posts will be the previous link. Like this:

◀ **2009** ... 2010 - - - - - **2011** - - - - - - - - - - - **2012** ►

**The question:** How do I in fastest way find the last year from a certain year that has posts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a query for a single post made before the currently viewed year. When sorted by date in descending order (the default) the first result will be from the most recent year with posts.

```
$current_year = get_query_var( 'year' );

$previous_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'date_query'  => array(
        'year'    => $current_year,
        'compare' => '<',
    ),
) );

if ( ! empty( $previous_posts ) ) {
    $previous_year = get_the_time( 'Y', $previous_posts[0] );
}
```

You can do the same to get the *next* year with posts, but you need to swap the order, otherwise you'll get the year of the latest post:

```
$next_posts = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order'       => 'ASC',
    'date_query'  => array(
        'year'    => $current_year,
        'compare' => '>',
    ),
) );

if ( ! empty( $next_posts ) ) {
    $next_year = get_the_time( 'Y', $next_posts[0] );
}
```